# Error: Could not request certificate: No route to host - connect(2) for "puppet.myname.homelab" port 8140

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns, puppet

I have two VMs setup to learn Puppet - one running puppetserver as my master and another as just a Puppet agent for DNS.

The VMs are running in Hyper-V (Windows 10) and are on the same virtual switch.

After setting up the internal DNS server using this Puppet module - https://github.com/ajjahn/puppet-dns my second, DNS VM can no longer connect to the puppetserver. I receive this error on `puppet agent -t` runs:

```
Error: Could not request certificate: No route to host - connect(2) for "puppet.myname.homelab" port 8140
```

- On the puppetserver I have reissued its own agent cert, which changed the cert from `puppet <sha-omitted>` to `"puppet.myname.homelab" <sha omitted> (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.myname.homelab")`
- Running `puppet agent -t` on the puppetserver to update itself works fine post cert renewal.
- I am able to successfully perform a `nslookup` on any of the hosts using the DNS server, and they do resolve with the new `myname.homelab` domain.
- I still have DHCP enabled on my home router, but I have it set to be the second nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf on both VMs:

  ```
  search myname.homelab  
  nameserver 192.168.1.107  
  nameserver 192.168.1.1
  ```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and Puppet 4 on both VMs. I have allowed port 8140 in UFW on both VMs, and have even tried disabling UFW with no luck.

I'm still learning Puppet and am a novice to networking, so any suggestions on what else to try and to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I slept on it and realized this morning that my router had reassigned my Puppetserver to a new IP, so the DNS A record for it was wrong, even though it was manually assigned in the router's DHCP.

Correcting that did the trick and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue but another cause: the firewwall on the puppet server blocked port 8140. The can be checked on the client as follows:

```
$ curl -k -I https://puppet:8140
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

After disabling the firewall on the server (e.g. systemctl stop firewalld):

```
$ curl -k -I https://puppet:8140
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 11:27:26 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 278
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

which is the expected output, and also the puppet agent runs as expected.